# U.S. Map jQuery plugin: change color of state based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the U.S. Map jQuery plugin to create a map. I will have some states that i will not use. I would like to get a collection of those states and set them to a specific color. I've tried many different things to no avail. Here is a simplified code sample to help illustrate what i am trying to do.

```
var disabledStates = ['OH', 'TX'];

$('#map').usmap({
   stateSpecificStyles: {
      disabledStates.forEach(function (state) {
         state: { fill: 'yellow' }
      });
   } 
});
```

Obviously, this code doesn't work. Just posting it to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first make the state style object, then apply it:

```
var disabledStates = ['OH', 'TX'];

// Array to object.
var myStyles = {}
for (var i = 0; i < disabledStates.length; i++) {
    myStyles[disabledStates[i]] = {fill: 'yellow'};
}

// Apply object.
$('#map').usmap({
    stateSpecificStyles: myStyles
});
```